# Healthy (environment / atmosphere / get-together / company etc.)

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning, idioms, expressions

I wonder what do you call a place / a get-together / a company / an environment, an atmosphere which is safe morally and sexually. In such a place etc. people do not use drugs, do not look for someone just to hook up with, and look at each other in a chaste way.
I am wondering if the word "[healthy](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/healthy)" works in this sense.

**Example:**

> **Cindy:** Did you go to the party last night? 
> **Barbara:** No! They have such get-togethers every other weeks, but I've never go to such places! 
> **Cindy:** How come? Is it something wrong with them? Is there someone you don't like? 
> **Barbara:** I don't like the relationships between them! The way they treat each other looks disgusting! They don't care about who you are, where you are from! Everyone has got an eye on you and just wants to take advantage of you! I regret going to one of their parties last year and I'm afraid of taking part in such occasions. Everyone was doped up and high! That was very scary. 
>  Their companies / get-togethers / atmosphere / environment is just not healthy at all!

First of all, I am looking for an adjective which can describe such conditions! Secondly, I have my doubts regarding e.g. "healthy" environment! Because, when I search it, I run into many pages that have discussed the phrase as a situation in which people enjoy clean air, stable climate, adequate water, sanitation and hygiene, safe use of chemicals, protection from radiation, healthy and safe workplaces, sound agricultural practices, health-supportive cities  and a preserved nature are all prerequisites for good health altogether which has nothing to do with what I need here.

I am wide open to any better, more correct or more common fixed phrase, idiom or expression.

Comment: The current term for _avoiding_ such an atmosphere is _safeguarding_, so she could perhaps say 'they don't feel safe at all." NB _A company_ usually means a business firm, so I'm not sure whether that is what you mean here.

Comment: No no @Kate Bunting! Here, the word "company" means a group of people. The forth definition in the following link: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/company

Comment: I was not about avoiding such places in my example. I am looking for an adjective which defines such places.

Comment: *Safe* seems to work just fine for me, maybe *comfortable*. I don't see anything wrong with *healthy* either. That said, neither of those are objective descriptions - to Barbara a party where she's getting chatted up might make for an *unhealthy* atmosphere, but to Cindy who wants to have a good time, a party where everyone's looking down on drinks, drugs and sex might be *unhealthy* as well.

Comment: I meant that safeguarding is avoiding _the creation of_ an atmosphere where vulnerable people feel unsafe. I guessed you meant _company_ in that sense. It's misleading if you use an article.

Comment: For which dialect are you speaking @Maciej Stachowski?

Comment: @A-friend I'm going to say GenAm, although a) I'm ESL and b) I don't believe there's a dialectal difference here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not following you. I see there is not a matter of dialect. Raising that question I was going to make sure whether you are a native speaker or not.

Comment: ***Healthy*** sounds to me like a rather tub-thumpingly "loaded" term for the intended sense here. For no reason I can put my finger on, near-synonymous ***wholesome** company / venues / pursuits / friends* seems a much better choice. Perhaps it's just that ***wholesome*** is more often used "semi-metaphorically" to mean "not depraved or corrupting", whereas ***healthy*** more often has the literal sense of "promoting good physical health".

Comment: @A-friend: Maciej has exceptionally good command of English for a non-native speaker. But as his previous comment implies, BrE or AmE aren't particularly relevant issues here. Except that *culturally*, much of American society (at least, *as publicly promoted*) is far more conservative (Christian) than Britain, so the general perception of what constitutes a "safe" environment for young people in the US might be considerably more restrictive than the same in Britain! For example, I suggest that in the US, what many would call *a wholesome environment* might actually be homophobic!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken @Maciej Stachowski your name sounds Russian. If so, I mean "Приличное место" by "healthy place".

Comment: @A-friend Polish, but I'll let it slide... :) Especially since that Russian translation was pretty helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## wholesome

As FumbleFingers said in a comment above:

> Healthy sounds to me like a rather tub-thumpingly "loaded" term for the intended sense here. For no reason I can put my finger on, near-synonymous wholesome company / venues / pursuits / friends seems a much better choice. Perhaps it's just that wholesome is more often used "semi-metaphorically" to mean "not depraved or corrupting", whereas healthy more often has the literal sense of "promoting good physical health".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wholesome) has this definition (my emphasis):

> **3a :** sound in body, mind, or ***morals***

Also, "wholesome" can idiomatically describe a place, company, an environment or an atmosphere in the sense of it being morally sound, **or** having a mentally healthy, supportive and friendly environment. For events like parties, get-togethers and meet-ups, "wholesome" only applies in the metaphorical sense of being "morally sound", as in, no sex and no intoxicants.

That said, someone like Barbara who believes a party like that is bad for them could naturally describe it as "unhealthy", as that's their opinion, or their assessment of how the party would affect them personally. Many people believe that sexual freedom and judicious use of drugs is a healthier lifestyle than abstinence and sobriety.

Comment: Brilliant! If I'd thought of looking at some dictionary definitions I'd probably have easily be able to see that they're more likely to mention ***morally** sound* in connection with ***wholesome*** than ***healthy***. In which case I might have posted an answer myself - but in the circumstances, many thanks for clearing up *my* doubts as well as responding to the OP.

Comment: Well, then "wholesome" can be used to describe "environment/atmosphere/place/company/get-together/meetup) without sounding awkward or unnatural to you @gotube?

Comment: @A-friend Yes, "wholesome" can describe all of those things, as I've now added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

The discussion in comments pointed me to the word **[decent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decent)**:

> conforming to standards of propriety, good taste, or morality

While still a rather positively-loaded word, it doesn't have the same implications of approval as *wholesome* or *healthy* - with those words, there's a heavy implication that the lack of alcohol and flirting is the right way to do things, while *decent* just describes the party or atmosphere as being in "good taste" without passing as much of a judgement.

(Note that *decent* also means *fairly good*, eg. *a decent drummer* - so make sure there's enough context to distinguish a *decent* (in good taste) party from a *decent* (satisfactory) party).

Another word I could use is **[proper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proper)**:

> correct according to social or moral rules

I'd consider *proper* a more objective term, although one with rather formal connotations - a *proper* atmosphere at a party would mean a more formal gathering in which people make specific effort to behave appropriately, while a *decent* atmosphere would just mean they're not indulging in any immoral acts. (What constitutes an immoral act is left as an exercise to the reader).

Comment: Very good suggestions @Maciej Stachowski. Thank you very much for being if help.